# How to prevent user log in from two devices

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, ionic2

I am developing mobile application in ionic 2. I want to design mechanism when user log in my website i must log out from my mobile application at the same time if user logged in mobile application then website must be log out. I am using same database for mobile and website. I am using jsonwebtoken for my mobile authentication. what is the best way to implement this mechanism in my ionic 2 application.

Comment: Could you specify the scope are you trying to restrict login only from multiple devices or just any other login ?

Comment: if you are using web tokens (which arent stored on your end) this will be impossible to prevent as you have no information of any session. If you have some sort of refresh token you could at least revoke this and let the access token expire

Comment: i want to prevent from multiple devices means weather website or mobile devices user must use one device at a time. website using session ids but mobile application used tokens. If i store web tokens in my database when user logged in so how can i compare with with website sessions.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to create a session table that will store the session details and will also store the unique ID and status that will be used to identify these sessions and tell us weather it is active or not. This id will be used as a reference to validate session for different devices, once the user logs in you will query into this table and check whether any existing session is there or not. If it is there change the status to false.

In the UI you will use setinterval to request for this session at regular time it can be 10 seconds or anything based on your requirement then inside setinterval make a call to backend that will be checking this session, if this session status is false then logout.

Comment: You are right exactly what i want to do but i do not have an idea how to use with tokens and session ids. is it possible to to use both and validate in my backend.

Comment: In that case you can check for session authentication based on the backend you are using